# Setting replication factor in Network Topology

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

If I have 2 datacentres, dc1 and dc2 with dc1 containing 2 nodes and dc2 containing 1 node; how will I define the replication factor in the keyspace if I want each node to have 2 replicas. for e.g. will I set dc1:2, dc2: 1 or dc1: 3, dc2:3

Comment: A node cannot have multiple replicas.  If you want two replicas in a DC, then you need *at least* two nodes in that DC.

Comment: Can I set the replication factor of a data center higher than the number of nodes in it i.e. suppose I've 2 data centers. dc1 has 3 nodes and dc2 has 2 nodes so can I set replication factor as dc1:4, dc2:1?

Comment: You could, but it wouldn't help any.  Plus your reads/writes will fail for anything done at consistency level ALL.  In the 2 replicas on 1 node scenario from your original question, your reads/writes will fail for anything done at LOCAL_QUORUM.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm bothering with silly questions but I wanted to understand whether, in case of a read query, consistency means that the given number of replica nodes are reachable/replying to a query or does it mean that the given number of replica nodes are providing the 'same' result for the query? I don't understand what you have stated above that reads/writes will fail for anything done at consistency level ALL.

Answer (score 1):

In NetworkTopologyStragegy you set the number of replicas per datacenter you want. For your example:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE demo
  WITH REPLICATION = { 
   'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 
   'dc1' : 1,
   'dc2' : 1 
  } ;
```

This will ensure that you will have two replicas of your data in your cluster. NetworkTopolgyStragegy will place one copy in dc1 and one in dc2. Of course this will put more data on your single node in dc2 as it has to hold all the data from both dc1 nodes.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how the data is stored considering both, the token values and replication factor. Please help me out.In your example, when we add a row to the table, the row will be sent to that node whose token matches with the hash value of the primary key. Apart from that, 1 replica will be created in dc 1 and 1 replica will be created in dc2. Is this correct. In this manner, the data will have in total 3 copies. Or will it have only 2 copies in total. And what about the case when we define zero as replication factor of one of the datacentres? Will the node store any data?

Comment: I'm also confused by the usage of the term replica. I read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27124394/5701173 that even the original is called as replica!

Comment: Also, can I set the replication factor of a data center higher than the number of nodes in it i.e. suppose I've 2 data centers. dc1 has 3 nodes and dc2 has 2 nodes so can I set replication factor as dc1:4, dc2:1?

Comment: In my example you will have a total of two copies. Cassandra uses the term replication factor which is defined on the keyspace and simply defines how many copys of your data your keyspace should keep. RF=2 means every piece of data is stored on two nodes, RF=3 three nodes, and so on - there is no "primary" data. NTS distributes those copies on datacenters. You can set RF=0 for a datacenter, then this dc wont hold the data at all.